# How to draw Venn diagrams (especially: complements) in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, circles, logic, venn-diagrams

What I am up to is to write some exercises dealing with logical formulas for my students, like:

[image: A \cup B]

And the students should draw these formulas on [Venn diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram). At the end of the lesson, I really would like to print the correct answer for them. I found a great resource on a forum thread at [latex-community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=6544&p=25539), which helped me a lot to make up some Venn diagrams with tikz, but have some problems with visualizing complements, like ~A.

A simple, modified version of the TeX file found on the forum linked above, can be seen below, which produces the following expression:

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \def\firstcircle{(90:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\secondcircle{(210:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\thirdcircle{(330:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}
    \clip \secondcircle;
    \fill[cyan] \thirdcircle;
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}
    \clip \firstcircle;
    \fill[cyan] \thirdcircle;
      \end{scope}
      \draw \firstcircle node[text=black,above] {$A$};
      \draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] {$B$};
      \draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] {$C$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Which looks like:

[image]

Could anyone please help me out plotting/defining some expressions dealing with complements? A nice example could be:

[image: $\overline{A \cap B}$]

That should look like: (image from [Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Venn1110.svg))

[image]

I do not insist on the red color :)

I would like to use the simplest possible solution, as I would like to mass generate the exercises with the help of [R](http://www.r-project.org/). So any suggestion dealing with gnuplot, R or any other opensource packages is welcome. Thank you!

---

**UPDATE (25/01/2011):** added details based on answers.

Thank you @Leo Liu, you helped me a lot! I modified a bit the code you suggested to be able to color the area outside of the two circles also (in the *H* universe), but have no idea how to set a background to that polygon also. The code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=gray]
% left hand
\scope
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2)
      (1,0) circle (1);
\fill (0,0) circle (1);
\endscope
% right hand
\scope
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2)
      (0,0) circle (1);
\fill (1,0) circle (1);
\endscope
% outline
\draw (0,0) circle (1) (0,1)  node [text=black,above] {$A$}
      (1,0) circle (1) (1,1)  node [text=black,above] {$B$}
      (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2) node [text=black,above] {$H$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the image generated:

[image]

I will also look for `even odd rule` in the near future which does not make sense for me at the moment but looks really simple and promising!

Comment: Not super relevant for drawing complements, but for venn diagrams in tikz you could check out: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/

Comment: Although a lot of time has passed, someone who wander here might also find this [link](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/set-operations-illustrated-with-venn-diagrams/) helpful.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are several ways to draw Venn diagrams. The simplest for `$\overline{A \cap B}$` may be:

```
\tikz \fill[even odd rule] (0,0) circle (1) (1,0) circle (1);
```

The key to this question is `even odd rule` in `TikZ` (based on PostScript and PDF).

[image: use even odd rule]

Moreover, you can also use `\clip` to fill the complement of a set, without using `even odd rule`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=gray]
% left hand
\scope
\clip (-1,-1) rectangle (2,1)
      (1,0) circle (1);
\fill (0,0) circle (1);
\endscope
% right hand
\scope
\clip (-1,-1) rectangle (2,1)
      (0,0) circle (1);
\fill (1,0) circle (1);
\endscope
% outline
\draw (0,0) circle (1)
      (1,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: use clipping]

Here, we find out that `TikZ` is lack of a `\unfill` command which is provided by MetaPost, thus we must use an extra rectangle to clip the path.

---

---

**For updated question:**

Well, I must say that this will be easier, if you fill `$A \cap B$` with white color:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=gray] (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\scope % A \cap B
\clip (0,0) circle (1);
\fill[white] (1,0) circle (1);
\endscope
% outline
\draw (0,0) circle (1)
      (1,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: fill with white]

However, it is not so easy to fill such a area using clipping (**warning: it's somewhat difficult to use, only for fun**):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=gray]
% left hand
\scope
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (0.5,2)
      (1,0) circle (1);
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (0.5,2);
\fill (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\endscope
% right hand
\scope
\clip (0.5,-2) rectangle (3,2)
      (0,0) circle (1);
\clip (0.5,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\fill (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\endscope
% outline
\draw (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\draw (0,0) circle (1)
      (1,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Hints:**

- The result using multiple path in one `\clip` command depends on the **direction** of the path.

[image: Explanation for direction of the clipping path]

- Use another `\clip` again to get rid of the half circle being filled.

Comment: Thank you @Leo Liu, that really looks simple and perfect! I need some time to read about this solution and understand the syntax, I will be back to accept the answer after some experiment!

Comment: I have just realized, that the example is not correct, as the area outside of both circles also should be colored. I added more details to my question (with example image).

Comment: @daroczig: I updated the answers, one is easy to use and the other using clipping is more powerful.

Answer (score 42):

An example for Venn diagrams with transparency by Till Tantau and Kjell Magne Fauske, from the [TikZ Example gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3cm,-5cm)}, fill opacity=0.5]
        \fill[red] \firstcircle;
        \fill[green] \secondcircle;
        \fill[blue] \thirdcircle;
        \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$A$};
        \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$B$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$C$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Stefan for posting (+1), this is really great indeed.

Comment: How are the color values combined in the overlap? It doesn't seem like red+green+blue should make deep blue.

Comment: @Trevor Alexander: I guess that is because of the order -first red is mixed with the white backgrund, and then green is put on top of that. Finally blue is mixed on top of that color to give the deep blue.

Comment: Is it possible to draw such diagrams without having to give exact coordinates?

Answer (score 17):

run it with `xelatex` if you need a pdf

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,4)
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt}
\psframe[fillcolor=red!30,fillstyle=solid](6,4)
\psclip{\pscircle(2,2){1.5}}
  \pscircle[fillcolor=white,fillstyle=solid](4,2){1.5}
\endpsclip
\pscircle(4,2){1.5}\pscircle(2,2){1.5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Herbert! I am not familiar with pstricks and XeTeX yet, but these look promising. I will look after based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 17):

A solution with the new package tkz-euclide ( based on TikZ )

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} 
\usetkzobj{all} 
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\color{Maroon}   
\tkzSetUpColors[background=fondpaille,text=Maroon]

\begin{document} 

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}  
   \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
   \begin{scope}
       \tkzClipCircle(A,B) \tkzClipCircle(B,A)
       \tkzFillCircle[color=blue!20](A,B)  
   \end{scope}
   \tkzDrawCircle(A,B)  
   \tkzDrawCircle(B,A)   
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image: Intersection]

Comment: and by the way, the optional argument `usenames` for `xcolor ` is obsolete for years ...

Comment: @ Herbert Why ? I have this option in the xcolor documentation and I use some color's names  from this option. I never see a warning with this option but I suppose that you are right. Where can I find this information ?

Comment: @AlainMatthes how can I add a label (A, B) to each of the circles and a label (H) to the universe?

Answer (score 13):

If you use MetaPost or Asymptote, there will be a different method: `buildcycle`.

For example, Asymptote:

```
size(200);
defaultpen(black+1);

pair A = (0,0), B = (1,0);
path inter = buildcycle(arc(A,1,-90,90), arc(B, 1,90,270));
path outer = box((-2,-2), (3,2));

fill(outer, mediumgray); unfill(inter);
// or use:
//     fill(outer ^^ inter, evenodd+mediumgray);
draw(outer ^^ circle(A,1) ^^ circle(B,1));
```

[image: result]

And you don't have to use a language to draw Venn diagrams. Inkscape can also deal with them.

Comment: @Leo Liu: and thanks also for this alternate solution!

Comment: @Leo How to manage the font with Inskape ? I think it's not a good solution with LaTeX. The best solutions and very well integrated are pstricks and tikz. Tools like geogebra or texgraph  are fine but you can not adjust the size of your figures automatically in conjunction with the text.

Comment: @Altermundus: There are some extensions to enable Inkscape to use LaTeX labels. See http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/ExtensionsRepository.

Comment: @Leo (+1) The [venn.mp](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/venn/venn.mp) macro might be useful too.

Comment: @Leo And for Asymptote, see e.g. http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/LaTeX-usage.html.

Comment: @Altermundus: Inkscape 0.48 can also export your SVGs as PDFs, with a complementary .tex file which takes care of text formatting and positioning (pretty much the same philosophy they use for EPS+TeX). I found this functionality to be a bit unreliable, but in the upcoming 0.48.1 (due any day now) this is said to be fixed.

Answer (score 12):

There's a **venn** package on CTAN:

"Creating Venn diagrams with MetaPost."

Example code (from README):

```
draw_venn_two(true,false,true,false) shifted (2in,1in);
```

draws a diagram with the outer box shaded, with the first circle but not
the second unshaded, with the intersection of the two shaded, and with the
second circle but not the first unshaded.  That is, this is a picture of 
the complement of the symmetric difference of A and B.

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution (+1), I'll have to check it out.

Comment: The "package" shouldn't be called "package". There is no documentation for it.

Answer (score 11):

User defined constants:

```
    \const{HalfCanvas}{1.5}% half of canvas width or height
    \const{InitAngleD}{30}% initial angle 
    \const{MainR}{1}% main radius
    \const{ChildR}{2}% child radius
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\def\const#1#2{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#1\endcsname{round(#2:3)}%
    \pstVerb{/#1 \csname#1\endcsname\space def}%
}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=12pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}


\def\init{%
    %
    % user defined constants
    \const{HalfCanvas}{1.5}% half of canvas width or height
    \const{InitAngleD}{30}% initial angle 
    \const{MainR}{1}% main radius
    \const{ChildR}{2}% child radius
    %
    % internal used constants
    \const{AngleAD}{InitAngleD}%
    \const{AngleBD}{InitAngleD+120}%
    \const{AngleCD}{InitAngleD+240}%
}

\def\hold{\psgrid\pause}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
        \init
        \pnode(\MainR;\AngleAD){A}
        \pnode(\MainR;\AngleBD){B}
        \pnode(\MainR;\AngleCD){C}

        \psset{linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,style=gridstyle,opacity=0.999}\hold
        \pscircle[fillcolor=blue](C){!ChildR}\hold

        \begin{psclip}{\pscircle[fillcolor=green](B){!ChildR}}
            \pscircle[fillcolor=red](C){!ChildR}
        \end{psclip}\hold

        \begin{psclip}{\pscircle[fillcolor=red](A){!ChildR}}
            \pscircle[fillcolor=blue](B){!ChildR}
        \end{psclip}\hold

        \begin{psclip}{\pscircle[fillstyle=none](A){!ChildR}}
            \pscircle[fillcolor=green](C){!ChildR}
        \end{psclip}\hold

        \psset{fillstyle=none}
        \begin{psclip}{\pscircle(A){!ChildR}\pscircle(C){!ChildR}}
            \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](B){!ChildR}
        \end{psclip}\hold

        \psset{linestyle=solid}
        \pscircle(A){!ChildR}\hold
        \pscircle(B){!ChildR}\hold
        \pscircle(C){!ChildR}
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a nice introduction I found to drawing Venn diagrams:

http://users.ju.edu/hduong/math220/venn_diagrams.pdf

I put it here, since this question is one of the first results google gives when looking for "how to draw Venn diagrams" (naturally), and also other places refer here, but I feel none of the answers give an introduction to drawing Venn diagrams for someone who doesn't know anything about using TikZ (as I was when I reached here). This introduction does explain the basics rather well.

Comment: I would suggest actually including what you can from the linked post in a full-fledged answer, rather than just linking to an outside source (thereby avoiding potential future link rot).

Comment: This is indeed useful, thank you @ur-ben-ari-tishler

Comment: The link attached in this answer is no longer useful. It is broken.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple package to Venn diagrams, maybe somebody likes this: [package venndiagram](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/venndiagram). I'm using it, it's enough for me.