# Metapost use venn package

Tags: metapost

I use TexShop, and I have successfully compiled an example which uses metapost code directly in LaTeX code ( by running pdflatex, then metapost, then finally pdflatex again).
this code uses `mpfic` option

Now I want to use the venn ( http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/venn ) package in my document. But `\usepackage{venn}` is causing not found error, and any command without venn package is not working as well.

So how do I setup the usage of `venn` package with metapost. I have installed it already using TeX live utility.

Comment: You can also make Venn diagrams with TikZ, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex

Answer (score 2):

I have never tried to include the source directly inside the .tex file but in case your trouble is with the metapost code it may help to start with a known-good stand-alone source.

I did this recently, so I suspect that it still works (although I have edited out some stuff I think is not needed so do let me know if it fails). Here is the input file. It draws the Venn diagram for the union.

```
% set.mp
%  MetaPost input file with chapter one pictures.
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
etex

input venn

outputtemplate := "%j-%2c.mps";
beginfig(0);
  draw_venn_two(false,true,true,true);
  % Label the sets (from pp 29 pf MetaPost manual)
  picture pa, pb;
  pa = thelabel(btex \tiny $A$ etex,   (.9venn_circle_left_shift,1.15venn_circle_top_shift));
  pb = thelabel(btex \tiny $B$ etex, (1.1venn_circle_right_shift,1.15venn_circle_top_shift));
  unfill bbox pa;
  draw pa;
  unfill bbox pb;
  draw pb;
endfig;

end
```

At a (Linux) command line I ran the four commands

- `mpost set.mp` followed by
- `tex mproof set-00.mps` followed by
- `dvips -Pwww -omproof.ps mproof` finally followed by
- `gv mproof.ps`;

this last pops up a viewer for the figure.

To include it in my doc I used this.

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{set-00.mps}
\end{center}
```

This is inside Beamer.  I don't see that I did anything special to get the graphicx system to recognize the .mps ending but I may have forgot the details; let me know.

(Edit: someone changed what I wrote and in particular dropped the necessary initial paragraph.  I added something like it back.)

Comment: Could you please include a picture showing off the Venn diagrams your method outputs? You can just press the image icon in the editing dialogue to upload one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the workflow is much simpler now with `luamplib`.

[image]

This is the source:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
  input venn
  beginfig(1);
  draw_venn_two(false, true, true, true);
  picture pa, pb;
  pa = thelabel("\footnotesize A", center venn_box shifted 13 left); 
  pb = thelabel("\footnotesize B", center venn_box shifted 13 right);
  unfill bbox pa; draw pa;
  unfill bbox pb; draw pb;
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

And the workflow

- compile with `lualatex` to produce a PDF file
- er, that's it.