# Using PGF in Lyx

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx

I just tried coping & pasting code from [How to draw Venn diagrams (especially: complements) in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex)

and I get errors ... I suppose I need to install/configure Lyx to use PGF/Tikz?

[image]

Comment: You need to add `\usepackage{tikz}` to your preamble (I think you can do this by selecting `LaTeX preamble` from the `Layout` menu).

Comment: I think you should change the Editor. I think in cases like this LyX reaches his capability

Comment: @Jake, I added `\usepackage{tikz}` under `Document > Settings > LaTeX preamble` I still got the same error.

Comment: @Marco, what editors do you recommend?

Comment: @Jake, thanks you got me on the right track! I needed `\usepackage{pgfplots}` too

Comment: @jiewmeng: Have a look at this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides
At the beginning TeXStudio is one of the best one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `\usepackage{pgfplots}` to your preamble. In LyX, you can edit the preamble under `Document | Settings | LaTeX Preamble`.