# Set of Venn Diagrams

Tags: venn-diagrams

What is the best way to draw four partially shaded venn-diagrams next to each other in the middle of a page? My goal is to depict the union, intersection, complement, etc.

Comment: in what way is this different to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex?rq=1 ?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. How can I get multiple ones side by side? I understand how to draw one but I can't get four of them together. Can I avoid a line break?

Comment: Don't put an empty line between `tikzpicture` environments, and they'll end up on the same line.