# Venn Diagram in LaTeX for $C\setminus (A \cap B \cap C)$

Tags: venn-diagrams

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=gray]
    \scope
        \clip (2.7,-2.54) rectangle (-1.5,1.5)
         (0,0) circle (1)
         (1.2,0) circle (1);
         \fill (0.6,-1.04) circle (1);
    \endscope
        \draw (0,0) circle (1) (0,1)  node [text=black,above] {$A$}
              (1.2,0) circle (1) (0,1)  node [text=black,above right,shift={(1,0.01)}] {$B$}
              (0.6,-1.04) circle (1) (1.1,-0.6) node [text=black, shift={(0.6,-1.1)}] {$C$}
              (2.7,-2.54) rectangle (-1.5,1.5) node [text=black,above] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

This is the output of the above code - not quite what I want. If you understand the set notation in my question you'll understand that I want C to be filled in except for the little middle section of the diagram where A and B and C are all intersecting (i.e. I want to not shade in the region corresponding to the set whose members are common to A and B and C).

I am not smart enough to work out how to use clipping to achieve this. Please help me!

Comment: Hi there! I recommend putting "venn" into the search box in http://www.texample.net/ You'll get many useful examples which should be helpful. Also, there is a tutorial on Venn diagrams on our website: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9682/11002

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Attention all!
Feel free to try to answer this question as I've set it up, but I've decided to simply insert an image of a Venn Diagram into my document for this case

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `vendiagram` package. Its very easy to use. Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,venndiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{venndiagram3sets}
\fillOnlyC
\fillBCapCNotA
\fillACapCNotB
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\[ C\setminus (A \cap B \cap C) \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The following code should do what you want (based on http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray] (0.6,-1.04) circle (1);
\begin{scope}
  \clip (0.6,-1.04) circle (1);
  \clip (1.2,0) circle (1);
  \fill[white] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\draw (0,0) circle (1) (0,1) node [text=black,above] {$A$};
\draw (1.2,0) circle (1) (1,1.01) node [text=black,above right] {$B$};
\draw (0.6,-1.04) circle (1) (1.7,-1.7) node [text=black] {$C$};

\draw (2.7,-2.54) rectangle (-1.5,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I did not know that you can use two clip commands in the same scope. I like your answer better than mine.

Answer (score 5):

### Requested Answer for  C \setminus (A \cap B \cap C)

To draw [image] you can nest two scopes and clips as follows.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % frame
    \draw (2.7,-2.54) rectangle (-1.5,1.5);
    % area
    \fill[gray] (0.6,-1.04) circle (1);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0.6,-1.04) circle (1) (1.1,-0.6);
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle (1);                
            \fill[white] (1.2,0) circle (1) (0,1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
    % outline
    \draw (0,0) circle (1) (0,1)  node [text=black,above] {$A$};
    \draw (1.2,0) circle (1) (0,1)  node [text=black,above right,shift={(1,0.01)}] {$B$};
    \draw (0.6,-1.04) circle (1) (1.1,-0.6) node [text=black, shift={(0.6,-1.1)}] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

---

### Not requested answer for  C \setminus (A \cap B)

To draw [image] you do not need neither clipping nor the "even odd rule", just draw circle in the right order.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % frame
    \draw (2.7,-2.54) rectangle (-1.5,1.5);
    % area
    \fill[gray] (0.6,-1.04) circle (1);
    \fill[white] (0,0) circle (1) (0,1);
    \fill[white] (1.2,0) circle (1);
    % outline
    \draw (0,0) circle (1) (0,1)  node [text=black,above] {$A$};
    \draw (1.2,0) circle (1) (0,1)  node [text=black,above right,shift={(1,0.01)}] {$B$};
    \draw (0.6,-1.04) circle (1) (1.1,-0.6) node [text=black, shift={(0.6,-1.1)}] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives the result.

[image]

Comment: This is not the needed drawing, I'm afraid.

Comment: @egreg How embarrassing, you are completely right! Thanks for pointing it out. I added another (now hopefully right) solution.

Comment: Apparently the second scope it unnecessary according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386294/40974), which is better than mine.