# Venn Diagram using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

EDIT:: 
I saw the question mentioned in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex) which the moderator considered mine duplicate. However, I couldn't see how mine is duplicate. My main problem is to write the text in the intersection of CAT B and CAT C.

I am trying to create the following Venn diagram.
[image]

Following is my code and output:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
\fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
\fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
\fill[blue!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
\end{scope}
\node at ( 90:2)    {CAT A};
\node at ( 210:2)   {CAT B};
\node at ( 330:2)   {CAT C};
\node [font=\small] {text1, text2, text3, text4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For line breaks in nodes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes

Comment: you might try the venndiagram package: https://ctan.org/pkg/venndiagram?lang=en

Comment: If you want to have the texts stacked, just use `\node [font=\small,text width=1cm] {text1, text2, text3, text4};` instead of `\node [font=\small] {text1, text2, text3, text4};`.

Comment: How this question is duplicate??? I vote for reopenning it.

Comment: No one of the answers showed how to write in the intersections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I provide two examples. The first has a different layout compared to what you posted because I recycled something I had done previously. The second example uses the `venndiagram` package.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{venndiagram}

\tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw=gray,text opacity=1,fill opacity=0.25,circle,minimum width=10cm,fill=#1,line width=2pt}}
\tikzset{label/.style={text width=1.5cm,font=\large\sffamily}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[blend mode=screen]
          \node [venn circle = yellow] (A) at (0,0) {};
          \node [label] (A1) at (-2.5,0) {Cat A};
%
          \node [venn circle = green] (B) at (5,0) {};
          \node [label] (B1) at (7.5,0) {Cat B};  
%             
          \node [venn circle = orange] (C) at (2.5,5) {};
          \node [label] (C1) at (2.5,6.25) {Cat C};
% Use a tabular to stack the text
          \node [label] (D) at (5,3.75){\begin{tabular}{l} text1,\\text2,\\text3,\\text4 \end{tabular}};
        \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{venndiagram3sets}[radius=5cm,overlap=3cm,
                         tikzoptions={text opacity=1,fill opacity=0.25},
                         labelOnlyBC={\begin{tabular}{l} text1,\\text2,\\text3,\\text4 \end{tabular}}]
   \fillBCapCNotA 
\end{venndiagram3sets}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

```
\node [font=\small, align=center] {text1, \\ text2, \\ text3, \\ text4};
```

as you need the align for several lines or

```
\node [font=\small, text width=1cm] {text1, text2, text3, text4};
```

Depending if you want it to happen automatically or manually.

[image]

Comment: I want the text in the intersection between A and C

Comment: give a position at the node: `\node [font=\small,align=center] at (30:2.2) {text1, text2,\\ text3, text4};` and change the circle to `\fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.8) circle (3);`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[green!30!white] ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at ( 90:2)    {A};
  \node at ( 210:2)   {B};
  \node [font=\Large] {AUB};
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4) node [text=black,above] {U};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```