# drawing in latex simple

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams, slideshow

[image: Ven type diagram]

I have a presentation. I want to draw it in latex and put in on my slide. Some kind tell me where to begin or tell me the code

Comment: I can tell where to begin: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: This site is not for do it for me type of questions. The solution is easily found several places including this site. http://www.google.com/search?q=venn+diagram+latex

Comment: You can just draw some simple shapes to achieve this. Have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26736/76279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this to get you started:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=7cm] (c1) at (0,0) {};

    \node[draw,ellipse, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=2cm] (e1) at (0,1) {};
    \node[draw,ellipse, minimum height=2cm,minimum width=4cm] (e2) at (1,1) {};

    \node[text width=3cm] (l1) at (6,6) {Topological `reunion'?};
    \node[text width=3cm] (l2) at (7,1) {AECH};
    \node[text width=3cm] (l3) at (0.5,-3) {Matrix module};

    \draw[->] (c1) -- (l1);
    \draw[->] (e2) -- (l2);
    \draw[->] (e1) -- (l3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Familiarise yourself with the various ways you can customize the positions, sizes, shape colours, arrows etc... to achieve what you want. Don't be afraid to search other answers on this site and just try things.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I could draw the circle, ellipse separately but not be lying inside the circle. I understand the trick.