# Plot difference of sets in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

The image below shows `$A\cup C$`.

[image: union of sets]

How could I plot the inverse, that is how would one fill the part of `B` not in `A` or `C` `$B - (A\cup C)$`, and leave `A` and `C` with no fill?

In case it's helpful, here is the code for making the picture shown:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[fill=lightgray] (0, 0) circle (1) {};
  \filldraw[fill=lightgray] (3.2, 0) circle (1) {};
  \draw (1.6, 0) circle (1) {};
  \node at (0, 0) {A};
  \node at (1.6, 0) {B};
  \node at (3.2, 0) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: A very detailed discussion of Venn diagrams can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex).

Comment: Thank you @kabenyuk! I have bookmarked the link you shared.

Comment: Minor note: the proper syntax for virvles is `circle[radius=1]` and the empty group `{}` isn't needed as it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewStacey. I guess I didn't realize that since my radius was the default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inconvenient of filling A and C in white is that if you have a couloured background, it will be bad looking.

To avoid that and keep A and C transparent, you can use `even odd rule` and `\clip`:

[image: even odd rule and clip]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\A{(0, 0) circle (1)}
        \def\B{(1.6, 0) circle (1)}
        \def\C{(3.2, 0) circle (1)}
        
        \begin{scope}
            \clip \B;
            \fill[lightgray,even odd rule] \A \B \C;
        \end{scope}
        
        \draw \A node {A} \B node {B} \C node {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, just didn't know it existed.

Comment: Nice! Feel free to accpet the answer that suits you the most, then.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: fill the circles with `B` first and at the back, and `A` and `C` on top with white fill, then draw a circle for `B` on top to get its edges:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[fill=lightgray] (0, 0) circle (1) {};
  \filldraw[fill=lightgray] (3.2, 0) circle (1) {};
  \draw (1.6, 0) circle (1) {};
  \node at (0, 0) {A};
  \node at (1.6, 0) {B};
  \node at (3.2, 0) {C};

  \filldraw[fill=lightgray] (8.6, 0) circle (1) {};
  \filldraw[fill=white] (7, 0) circle (1) {};
  \filldraw[fill=white] (10.2, 0) circle (1) {};
  \draw (8.6, 0) circle (1) {};
  \node at (7, 0) {A};
  \node at (8.6, 0) {B};
  \node at (10.2, 0) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: union and difference]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some code of the cheap and nice way of @Sandy G (deleted! don't know why ^^)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\pagecolor{yellow!50}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{1.6} 
\fill[cyan!50] (\a,0) circle(1);
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle(1) (2*\a,0) circle(1);
\draw (\a,0) circle(1);
\path (0,0) node {$A$} (\a,0) node {$B$} (2*\a,0) node {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and a translation to Asymptote

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
real a=1.6;
path p=unitcircle;

fill(shift(a,0)*p,magenta+white);
filldraw(p^^shift(2a,0)*p,white);
draw(shift(a,0)*p);

label("$A$"); label("$B$",(a,0)); label("$C$",(2a,0));

shipout(bbox(5mm,Fill(yellow+white)));
```