# Making the environment of A Cap B less thick

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I decrease the thickness of the line encompassing A intersection B? This is my Code:

```
\documeentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=1.7, line width = 0.2cm}, labelA= {}, labelB={}, showframe=false, shade={}]
\setpostvennhook{
\draw (labelA) node[above=0.2cm, left=1.1cm]{\LARGE $A$};
\draw (labelB) node[above=0.2cm, right=1.1cm]{\LARGE $B$};}
\begin{scope}[pattern= horizontal lines]
\fillACapB
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[pattern= north east lines]
\fillACapB
\end{scope}
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

I want it to be something like this:
[image]

Comment: Maybe have a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex it might help.

Comment: Or https://latexdraw.com/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-in-latex/

Comment: Worst case you have to draw the diagram manually. Should not be very hard, figure out some way to draw circle section, fill a region, draw an arc etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=8pt] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\filldraw[fill=white] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\clip (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\fill[pattern=crosshatch] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two circles and area between them]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=8pt] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm] (60:3) circle[radius=2cm];
\filldraw[fill=white] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm] (60:3) circle[radius=2cm];
\clip (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\clip (60:3) circle[radius=2cm];
\fill[pattern=crosshatch] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three circles and their intersections]

Comment: Please can you also help me with the one of three sets A, B and C shaded in A intersection B intersection C. Please. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: See edit. You should normally start a new question for addition questions. -remember there is no limit on how many new question you can ask, and if you show some effort, all question will attract helpfull people.

Comment: Thank you. I will note that.

Answer (score 2):

Just to play a bit (if you want to do more complex diagrams, you'll have to calculate the angles more accurately).

[image: A cap B thinner]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[name path=circleA] (0,0) circle [radius=3];
        \path[name path=circleB] (4,0) circle [radius=3];
        \path[name intersections={of=circleA and circleB}] ;
        \draw[red,fill=orange] (intersection-1) arc(132:228:3) arc(-48:48:3);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (intersection-1) arc(48:312:3) arc(-132:132:3) -- cycle; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

A second approach (which I don't really like because of the white fill which doesn't allow to have something under the picture, but anyway it's quite unlikely) is the following where the lines seem better to my eyes.

[image: V2]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[name path=circleA] (0,0) circle [radius=3];
        \path[name path=circleB] (4,0) circle [radius=3];
        \path[name intersections={of=circleA and circleB}] ;
        
        \draw[red,line width=15pt] (intersection-1) arc(48:312:3) arc(-132:132:3) -- cycle; 
        \fill[white] (intersection-1) arc(48:312:3) arc(-132:132:3) -- cycle; 
        \draw[red,fill=orange] (intersection-1) arc(132:228:3) arc(-48:48:3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```