# Two-set and three-set diagrams: venndiagram package

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, venn-diagrams

I just wanted to know if there are any packages that build two or three intersecting sets, where you can put a number inside them, a capital letter on the set and with the universe set indicated a capital letter. Thank you.

See the example below.

[image]

### Follow up 2023-10-16

I have these two MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelOnlyA={1},labelOnlyB={2},labelOnlyC={3},
labelOnlyAB={4},labelOnlyAC={5},labelOnlyBC={6},labelABC={7},
labelNotABC={8}]
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code with 2 sets not work well if I write `labelOnlyAB={4}`. In fact the 4 is missing in the `A∩B`. It is necessary to write `labelAB={4}` instead of `labelOnlyAB={4}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelOnlyA={5},labelOnlyB={7}, labelAB={4},labelNotAB={15}]
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> How can I put the set `U` outside the rectangle and upper right above the rectangle?

Comment: [tikz pgf - How to draw Venn diagrams (especially: complements) in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1) [How to draw a Venn diagram in TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101839/how-to-draw-a-venn-diagram-in-tikz)

looks like nothing apart from TikZ.

Comment: You can use https://ctan.org/pkg/venndiagram, when you allow circles. It's built on Tikz, so you can add labels, lines etc. easily.

Comment: @user202729  Thank you very much.

Comment: @MS-SPO Thank you very much. The problem is that sets cannot be colored with venndiagram.

Comment: @MS-SPO The universe set is also missing.

Comment: @Sebastiano, right, the manual isn‘t verbose about this. But see here, as it‘s still tikzish: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661252/245790.

Comment: The answers to [Q67395](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67395) cover all possible 3-sets. And [Q266326](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266326) is about the 2-sets.

Comment: @MS-SPO I have put 2 MWE.

Comment: @user202729 I have put 2 MWE.

Comment: `labelOnlyAB` is a 3-set only key as per the manual. You can use `\setpostvennhook{\node[below right]at(venn bottom left){$U$};}` to add further TikZ code to the diagram.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Using `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,venndiagram,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelOnlyA={5},labelOnlyB={7}, labelAB={4},labelNotAB={15}]
\setpostvennhook{\node[above right]at(venn bottom right){$|U|=50$};}
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
` I have not `$|U|=50$` at top right above the rectangle.

Comment: See page 6 and Ex. 6 on page 8 in the manual about `\setpostvennhook`, i.e. relate to `venn top left` if I don't get it wrong. https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram/venndiagram.pdf . Results: see the example doc: https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram/samples/venn-sample.pdf

Comment: @Sebastiano [Looks good to me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKCQW.png). `venn bottom right` is obviously the bottom right corner, `above right` (= `anchor = south west`) just specifies the nodes placement in relation to the `at` place. Use `venn top right` instead. (Unfortunately, the rectangle is not a node, the package just defines coordinates for the four corners.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Perfect!!!! Thank you very vey very very much. I give me a downvote. I not know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

By the comments of @Qrrbrbirlbel user I have found the correct aspect.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,venndiagram,tikz} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelOnlyA={5},labelOnlyB={7}, labelAB={4},labelNotAB={15}] 
\setpostvennhook{\node[above right] at (venn top right){$|U|=50$};}
\end{venndiagram2sets} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelOnlyA={1},labelOnlyB={2},labelOnlyC={3},
labelOnlyAB={4},labelOnlyAC={5},labelOnlyBC={6},labelABC={7},
labelNotABC={8}]
\setpostvennhook{\node[above right] at (venn top right){$|U|=30$};}
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]