# Coloured circles of venndiagramm and to change the labels

Tags: color, labels, venn-diagrams

This question is related by two questions:

[Venndiagram with 4-sets: how to change the .sty file with modifications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698942/venndiagram-with-4-sets-how-to-change-the-sty-file-with-modifications)

[Two-set and three-set diagrams: venndiagram package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698589/two-set-and-three-set-diagrams-venndiagram-package)

Now I have this code with 3 sets:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelOnlyA={5},labelOnlyB={4},labelOnlyC={2},
labelOnlyAB={1},labelOnlyAC={3},labelOnlyBC={4},labelABC={5},
labelNotABC={8}]
\setpostvennhook{\node[above right] at (venn top right){$|U|=30$};}
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and another with 2 sets:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelOnlyA={5},labelOnlyB={7}, labelAB={4},labelNotAB={15}]
\setpostvennhook{\node[above right] at (venn top right){$|U|=30$};}
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### My requests are:

> 1. Is it possible to change the label of `A`, `B` or `C` with other letters (for example `M`, `F`, `O`, etc.) using `venndiagram` package for two or three sets of the drawing?
> 2. Is it possible to coloured only the circle of the sets using `venndiagram` package for two or three sets of the drawing?

Comment: For what strange reason is there a request for closure to my question?

Comment: The manual describes various `\fill…` macros. It also has the `shade` key.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes I have seen. I think that the color is only lightgray.

Comment: Yeah, as I said before, the package isn't very versatile. You will either need to overwrite the color lightgray locally or some other way to set `\@venn@shade` (or use the shade key outside of the optional argument of the environments). We can of course define a bunch of commands that so this for you or patch all the `\fill…` macros (but most of them are being defined right there in the `\begin{venndiagramXsets}`). It's either manual, half-automatic with another set of macros or reimplementation.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You are free to do with venndiagram whatever you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram/venndiagram.pdf) I can see that your first request is easy, but your second is a bit harder.

[image]

I produced the picture above using this version of your 3-circle diagram:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[
    labelA=$M$, labelB=$N$, labelC=$O$,  % <-- change circle labels
    tikzoptions={draw=red},              % <-- draw all lines in red
    labelOnlyA={5},labelOnlyB={4},labelOnlyC={2},
    labelOnlyAB={1},labelOnlyAC={3},labelOnlyBC={4},labelABC={5},
    labelNotABC={8}]
\setpostvennhook{\node[above right] at (venn top right){$|U|=30$};}
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

I cannot see a way of getting it to draw the frame in a different colour from the circles.

Comment: Great Thruston.  MIlle grazie. +1

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Thruston's answer:

You can disable drawing the frame first and than manually draw it using `\draw[black] (venn top right) rectangle (venn bottom left);`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[
    labelA=$M$, labelB=$N$, labelC=$O$,  % <-- change circle labels
    tikzoptions={draw=red},              % <-- draw all lines in red
    labelOnlyA={5},labelOnlyB={4},labelOnlyC={2},
    labelOnlyAB={1},labelOnlyAC={3},labelOnlyBC={4},labelABC={5},
    labelNotABC={8},
    showframe=false                      % <-- disable frame
]
\setpostvennhook{\node[above right] at (venn top right){$|U|=30$};}
% draw frame in black
\draw[black] (venn top right) rectangle (venn bottom left);
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thank you further for the implementation of Thruston's response. I do not understand why an attempt is being made to close my question. +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano I don’t know either. Maybe because it contains two questions instead of just one. I voted for “keep open”.

Comment: Thank you very very much. But I have seen that the closure is `Needs more focus
This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.`. For me it is not true.

Comment: @Sebastiano I'm no close voter, but your post obviously contains multiple questions, and not just a single question, that is a fact and has nothing to do with subjective interpretation, and it's not like you could say one of the questions is just a boundary condition to the other, they are two completely independent questions, which just happen to be about the same package.

Comment: @Skillmon Hi. I find it all so so strange. I found it unnecessary to break my request into two separate questions. What is the point? I'm sorry but I don't interact with any user in this way.